Subreport Only Displays Last Row in Main Report in JasperReports studio
I am working with a main report in JasperReports that includes a subreport to display elements from a database. The subreport fetches the data correctly and works fine when run independently. However, in the main report, only the last row of the subreport is displayed.

The subreport is placed within the Detail band of the main report. I need the subreport to repeat for multiple products.
The subreport receives a parameter (elementId) from the main report and fetches data based on this parameter.
Inside the subreport, I have a frame that is also placed within the Detail band. I want the frame to repeat for multiple sub-elements.

How can I fix this issue so that all rows are displayed in the main report?

Few things to check:

Make sure that the subreport uses the same data source as the main report and the parameter value is correct.
Check if the height of the detail band in the main report is greater than or equal to the height of the subreport. Also sounds like the height of the subreport should be equal to the height of the frame.
If the subreport only needs the detail band, all other bands can be removed to make sure its not getting truncated.
You could also check Print When expressions in both reports to make sure there's no conditional logic preventing them from displaying.

